# unable to delete row from table using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I just wanted to delete row from respective row. I have tried code for that you can see in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sneh_pandya/gaTes/#&togetherjs=huyceVKRyp).Its quite simple but still i am getting error.
my code for removing tr is

```
$(document).ready.(function(){
 $("#table-lst-regions .deleteLink").on("click",function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");

    tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
        tr.remove();
    });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that new added .deleteLink are not subscibed on click

You can change for example defenition for delete link with onclick attribute

```
<a class ="deleteLink" onclick="deleteRow(this);">
```

and add function delete

```
function deleteRow(el) {
        var tr = $(el).closest('tr');
        tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");

        tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
            tr.remove();
        });
      return false;
    }
```

Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/48MRf/2/

Comment: It works thanks alot..is there any method for editing directly inside the `tr`

Comment: You can create inputs with display none and show them on click edit also show button Save instead Edit with appropriate handler for it. Or you can use existing plugin for it for example http://jquery.iceburg.net/tableEditor/demo.php

Comment: @SNEHPANDYA Also take a look on js framework, like Knockout, Angularjs, Ember and so on. For example http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html It allows create more clean solution than just using jquery.